# SELECT on INNER JOIN taking 9 hours (and counting) to complete

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm using a **sqlite database** I have from the output of another script. I have a query that is taking a huge amount of time to complete. The `samples` table and `multiclass` table both have **the same ~4,000,000 `name`'s.** The multiclass table has one row for each name (**4 million rows**), and the sample table could have one or many rows for each name (**>100 million rows**). I am joining on the names and summing the count grouped by the tax_id, day, and sample that names belong to. **This query should return ~25000 rows**

Here is a toy version of the schema and query I'm using:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/7fff3/1)

**SQLite (SQL.js) Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE samples 
    (
     name varchar(20), 
     day integer, 
     sample integer,
     count integer
    );

CREATE TABLE multiclass 
    (
     name varchar(20), 
     tax_id varchar(20), 
     details varchar(30)
    );

INSERT INTO samples
(name, day, sample, count)
VALUES
('seq1', 204, 37, 50),
('seq2', 205, 37, 50),
('seq2', 206, 37, 50),
('seq3', 204, 37, 50),
('seq4', 205, 37, 50),
('seq4', 206, 37, 50);

INSERT INTO multiclass
(name, tax_id, details)
VALUES
('seq1', 'Vibrio', 'unimportant'),
('seq2', 'Shewenella', 'still_unimportant'),
('seq3', 'Vibrio', 'also_unimportant'),
('seq4', 'Shewenella', 'doesntmatter');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT tax_id, day, sample, SUM(count) 
FROM samples INNER JOIN multiclass USING(name) 
GROUP BY tax_id, day, sample 
ORDER BY day, sample;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/7fff3/1/0)**:

```
|     tax_id | day | sample | SUM(count) |
|------------|-----|--------|------------|
|     Vibrio | 204 |     37 |        100 |
| Shewenella | 205 |     37 |        100 |
| Shewenella | 206 |     37 |        100 |
```

I am very new to SQL and am not sure how to proceed. This is a query I would **only need to execute once**. so I'm not sure adding indexes to the table is appropriate.

**Is there a different way to construct the query to make it run faster?** Would adding indexes make sense or take too long? If it is taking 9 hours, is it likely to still be hung up on the SQL, or is something else going wrong?

**Edit:** updated question to include database schema and intended results. I am currently building indexes on the samples.name column, it's been running for over 4 hours (using a node on a cluster environment with 60 Gigs of ram and many cpus).

Comment: On the Python side, the only "optimization" I can see in your code would be to avoid the call to `cursor.fetchall()` and directly pass `cursor` to `writer.writerows()` (you have a typo in your snippet BTW), but I wouldn't expect any significant performance boost from this.

Comment: TL;DR : add proper indexes on your tables.

Comment: Would indexes be appropriate if I only need to execute the query once? Or would it take just as long to build the indexes as to do the query? How do I chose which columns to index?

Comment: add index on name column will improve query perfromance

Comment: Yes, the index will help, even for one query, because your query has to do one lookup on the `multiclass` table (which is a full table scan without an index) for each row in `samples`.

Comment: For the volume of data you are using and the types of queries that you are running, SQLite might be underpowered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the version of sqlite3 that was installed on the cluster I was using. The version on the cluster was 3.6.20. It seems incredible, but downloading the binary for 3.9.2 from the sqlite website and running the exact same query completed in less than 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

This query:

```
SELECT tax_id, day, sample, SUM(count) 
FROM samples INNER JOIN
     multiclass
     ON samples.name = multiclass.name 
GROUP BY tax_id, day, sample 
ORDER BY day, sample;
```

is pretty simple.  An index on either `samples(name)` or `multiclass(name)` would normally be recommended.

However, there is a hint in your question that both tables contain 4 million rows, but you are only expecting 25,000.  I suspect that you have duplicate names in each table.  To determine the number of intermediate rows generated by the `join`, run this query:

```
select sum(s.cnt * m.cnt), max(s.cnt * m.cnt)
from (select name, count(*) as cnt from samples group by name
     ) s join
     (select name, count(*) as cnt from multiclass group by name
     ) m
     on s.name = m.name;
```

I am guessing that you will get a really large number, explaining why the query is taking so long.

Unfortunately, at this point, I don't have  real answer on how to solve the problem, because your question doesn't specify what you actually want the query to produce.  However, aggregating the tables *before* joining them is likely to be one possible solution.

Comment: Each name is unique in multiclass (~4,000,000) but not in samples (>100,000,00). The reason I expect only 25,000 rows is there are that many combinations of tax_id, sample, and day.

Comment: I've edited my question to include the inteded results of the query and more information on the size of each table. I am running the query you suggested, but it hasn't finished yet (it has been 20 minutes)

Comment: I am currently adding an index on the name column of the samples table. I updated my question to show my desired output of the query and the schema of the tabled.